# Appending entries into a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Essentially, I' trying to end up with an array that looks like this:

```
{
    "projects" : [{
        "project" : "Project One",
        "tasks" : [{
            "name" : "Task One"
        }, {
            "name" : "Task Two"
        }, {
            "name" : "Task Three"
        }]
    }, {
        "project" : "Project Two",
        "tasks" : [{
            "name" : "Task One"
        }, {
            "name" : "Task Two"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I currently have the following array and a script which look at each element of tasks and checks to see that it's not already in a list of project names, then inserts the first one if it's not, and *should* add a second element if it is, but that's where I'm a little stuck:

```js
var tasks = [{
        "name" : "Task One",
        "project" : "Project One"
    }, {
        "name" : "Task One",
        "project" : "Project Two"
    }, {
        "name" : "Task Two",
        "project" : "Project One"
    }, {
        "name" : "Task Three",
        "project" : "Project One"
    }, {
        "name" : "Task Two",
        "project" : "Project Two"
    }]


var projectNames = [];
var projects = [];
for ( i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    if (projectNames.indexOf(tasks[i].project) < 0) {
        // checks to see that it's not the projectNames list, and inserts the first entry
        projectNames.push(tasks[i].project);
        projects.push({
            project : tasks[i].project,
            tasks : {
                name : tasks[i].name
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if that project is already in the list, append the next entry
        var ind = projectNames.indexOf(tasks[i].project);
        projects[ind].tasks.push({
            name : tasks[i].name
        });
    }
}
```

I'm under the impression that `projects[ind].tasks.push()` can't be used, but I'm not sure what the correct thing to replace it with would be?

(Equally if there are any better methods of getting from the first array to the second, I'm always happy to learn something new)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to have the code as a runable snippet?

Comment: @RobG Added the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
projects.push({ project: tasks[i].project, tasks: { name: tasks[i].name } });
```

You are adding *tasks* as an object, not an array. You should add it as an array with the object as its sole element:

```
projects.push({ project: tasks[i].project, tasks: [{ name: tasks[i].name }] });
```

Below is an alternative solution that might be "better" for some criteria, but for maintainability I think the OP is fine. I've changed the names of the tasks to show that the tasks are assigned to the correct project.

```js
var tasks = [{"name" : "Proj one, Task One", "project" : "Project One"},
             {"name" : "Proj two, Task One", "project" : "Project Two"},
             {"name" : "Proj one, Task Two", "project" : "Project One"},
             {"name" : "Proj one, Task Three", "project" : "Project One"},
             {"name" : "Proj two, Task Two", "project" : "Project Two"}
            ];

var projectNames = [];
var groupedTasks = tasks.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
                     var projectName = obj.project;
                     var idx = projectNames.indexOf(projectName);
                     if (idx == -1) {
                       projectNames.push(projectName);
                       idx = acc.projects.length;
                       acc.projects.push({project:projectName,tasks:[]});
                     }
                     acc.projects[idx].tasks.push({name:obj.name});
                     return acc;
                   }, {projects:[]});
                   
console.log(groupedTasks);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and for thisArg an object, if the same project is already created.

```js
var object = { "tasks": [{ "name": "Task One", "project": "Project One" }, { "name": "Task One", "project": "Project Two" }, { "name": "Task Two", "project": "Project One" }, { "name": "Task Three", "project": "Project One" }, { "name": "Task Two", "project": "Project Two" }] },
    result = { projects: [] };

object.tasks.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.project]) {
        this[a.project] = { project: a.project, task: [] };
        result.projects.push(this[a.project]);
    }
    this[a.project].task.push({ name: a.name });
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But this doesn't tell the OP where their issue is.

Comment: @RobG, right, you did, but *(Equally if there are any better methods of getting from the first array to the second, I'm always happy to learn something new)*

Comment: Fair enough. There are no criteria for *better* so I guess you can make them whatever you like. ;-)

Comment: @RobG `forEach` over `for(;;)` is one clear criterion ;-)

Comment: "plus" 1 for using `thisArg` as a "direct" reference for resulting object

Comment: I think that's a bit hacky personally; I'd rather see a named reference. It's still a good answer though.

Comment: its just a temp variable.

Comment: Most variables are temporary :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is already with a correct answer, i will leave here a function for **group by** that **can be useful to you or anyone that passes here** in the future.

```js
 var tasks = {
     "tasks": [{
        "name": "Task One",
        "project": "Project One"
     }, {
        "name": "Task One",
        "project": "Project Two"
     }, {
        "name": "Task Two",
        "project": "Project One"
     }, {
        "name": "Task Three",
        "project": "Project One"
     }, {
        "name": "Task Two",
        "project": "Project Two"
     }]
  };

function groupBy(array, f_gb, f_content) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function(o) {
        var group = f_gb(o);
        groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
        if(f_content == null)
          groups[group].push(o);
        else
          groups[group].push(f_content(o));
    });
    return groups;
}

//An you call the group by like this:
var result = groupBy(tasks.tasks, 
    // function from what to filter from 
    function(item) {
        return item.project;
    }, 
    // optional: what to chose from the object filtered
    function(item){
        return { name : item.name};
    }
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your output isn't quite what the OP is after. It may or may not be more sensible, depending on what the subsequent operations on the data are.

Comment: I know, so i put this short line _remember that you can change the call to the group by to change the output format_ you can call the group by formating the outuput on the 3 arg `f_content`

Comment: Yeah that's cool. My comment was observation rather than criticism as such.

Comment: Rather than linking to another site, better to make your code a runable snippet here.